# Supersized JQuery plugin displaying below content on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, supersized

I am using the Supersize plugin and it works fine on Chrome, FF and Safari but (suprise, surprise) not on IE9 (and 8 and 7).

The background images are appearing below my content, not behind it.

See the site here:http://host.pixelframe.net.au/~pptestco/

I think this should be a css fix as the Supersized images sit below all other content in a `ul` with the styles:

```
display: block;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -999;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Would anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

OK - it seems the CMS I was using (ModX Revo) came preloaded with the wrong (or no) DOCTYPE.

I've added

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

To my templates (above the `<html>`) tag and it seems ok!